# Assign value in json then send it with requests

Tags: python, python-requests

```
url = "url"
headers = CaseInsensitiveDict()

headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer mytoken"


headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"

profile_id='string'
data = """
{
    "browsersIds": [
        "{{profile_id}}"
    ]
}

resp = requests.patch(url, headers=headers, data=data)
```

the problem is that I cannot assign profile_id variable in the JSON therefore i got 400 bad requests

Comment: Maybe make `data` an f-string and only use one set of curly braces around `profile_id`? Your code also won't run, as you haven't closed the multi-line string.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the content type header.

Use `json` argument with a dictionary rather than needing to create a template string

```
profile_id='string'
data = {
    "browsersIds": [
        profile_id
    ]
}

resp = requests.patch(url, headers=headers, json=data)
```